# How to sum multiple rows on trigger update?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a trigger on update on table `[CART]` to count and insert value to other table `[HEADERS]` to column `[SUM]`. It works but only for 1 row where `[CART].[NUMBER] = [HEADERS].[NUMBER]`. Column `[NUMBER]` in `[CART]` is not unique and i want to count all values from `[CART]` where `[NUMBER]` is identical. It means `[AMOUNT]*[PRICE]` for each row with same number, add this and insert into column `[HEADERS].[SUM]`

Here is what i got:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[sum] ON [dbo].[CART] AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @RESULT DECIMAL
    DECLARE @AMOUNT FLOAT
    DECLARE @PRICE FLOAT
    DECLARE @NUMBER FLOAT
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE([NUMBER]) or UPDATE([AMOUNT]) or UPDATE([STATUS])
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @AMOUNT=[AMOUNT],@PRICE=[PRICE],@NUMBER=[NUMBER] FROM inserted 
        IF @NUMBER is not NULL
            BEGIN 
                SELECT @RESULT=@AMOUNT * @PRICE 
                UPDATE HEADERS SET SUM=@RESULT WHERE NUMBER=@NUMBER
            END
    END 
GO
```

I'm not really good at SQL and i cant find correct syntax for this task. Can you help me?

Comment: A trigger fires **once** per DML statement, not once per row in a DML statement. This trigger *assumes* an `UPDATE` will only ever contain 1 row, and so your process will only work for one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger code does not handle cases when multiple rows are updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[sum] ON [dbo].[CART] AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE([NUMBER]) or UPDATE([AMOUNT]) or UPDATE([STATUS])
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE H
        SET    [SUM] = I.AMOUNT * I.PRICE 
        FROM   inserted I
               INNER JOIN HEADER H ON I.NUMBER = H.NUMBER
    END 
GO
```